# Css display - Width menu when hover on li

Tags: html, css

I have css width problem with my menu and submenu

My menu is horizontaly like -

```
<ul>
<li> Menu <div style="diplay:none"> Submenu </li>
<li> Menu <div style="diplay:none"> Submenu </li>
</ul>
```

The width of `<li>` is auto, when hover on `<li>` the  display but when the div width is bigger than the`<li>` ,there is a gap

I want that the `<li>` width doesn't move whenever I hover

Do you have a solution to keep `<li>` width fixed when I hover ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I believe this question has been answered before. It looks like you're asking how to create a dropdown menu.

Comment: Hello , no i have my dropdown menu but i want to fix the width of li when a submenu is open

Comment: Typically the submenu is positioned absolutely within the parent element (which uses relative positioning) so it doesn't take up any space.

Comment: Yes but i can't deal with an absolute position so i use relative position

Comment: So share your code to represent the issue, including css, so we can help...

Comment: It's the same code than in the example so when hover , display:none become display:relative

Comment: @LionelB you mean `display: block;`? Why not just include that in your post if it's so simple?

Comment: @LionelB your code **is not a a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**. Please provide one, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you tell us, without an MCVE, _"I can't deal with absolute position."_ We have no idea if that's a technical issue or if you're a novice coder that isn't fully aware of the options and techniques available to you.

Comment: Where are your closing divs? Likely this does not render correctly if you do not close your div.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad example but @hungerstar solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically dropdown menus are positioned absolutely within their relatively positioned parent element so they do not take up any space.

Here is a basic example. Modify to your needs.

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba( 123, 123, 123, 1 );
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba( 123, 123, 123, 0.5 );
}
.has-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.has-submenu li {
  display: block;
}
.has-submenu > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.has-submenu:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="has-submenu">
    Item with submenu
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , it's work i forgot to put position absolute on this .has-submenu > ul

Comment: Cool, just make sure you have `position: relative;` on the correct parent/ancestor element so the submenu doesn't end up way across the page somewhere.

Comment: Yes i just understand that and it's why i didn't use absolute position